# Why silent push notification not work properly in background in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am using silent push notification in iOS app but not work properly in background while it work fine in foreground. I am unable to find out the what is the problem behind it.
Please help me

Comment: Please explain the meaning of silent here?

Comment: how do you define work fine? And please explain what do salient push notification mean here.

Comment: I also encounter the same. anyone find out ?

Answer (score 2):

You should enable background mode for your app.
As per [iOS developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).

> To support silent remote notifications, add the remote-notification value to the UIBackgroundModes array in your Info.plist file.

Also I believe that silent notifications work in background state. But that is only for `UIApplicationStateBackground` but after some time the app goes into suspended state and silent notifications wont work here. Needless to say it wont work when app is in terminated state

Supported states for silent push notifications would be
`UIApplicationStateActive`,`UIApplicationStateInactive`, `UIApplicationStateBackground`. But this is something I have heard from a friend who has actually worked on it.

Hope it helps you. Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I kept listening for ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground ), but never saw it fire. UIApplicationStateInactive got it.